# Does CoA always bind to organic molecules through a thiol bond?

Tags: biochemistry

Does CoA always bind to organic molecules through a thiol bond? Sometimes I see it written as SCoA in textbooks but sometimes it's just written as CoA, are those actually chemically different, or just laziness on the part of the author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coenzyme A (CoA). As you can see, it has an -SH group at its end. So when it interacts with other reagents, it forms thiolesters. CoA is just shorter.

[image: Coenzyme A]

Comment: Your answer is correct. However, I would mention a third alternative that the questioner may encounter — the one I prefer myself. This is not to use SCoA, but HSCoA in equations. That way e.g. acetylCoA can be written as CH3CO-SCoA and the chemistry of the reaction is apparent.

Comment: @David `CoA-S-Ac` is a term  for acetyl CoA, that I have commonly encountered.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Fashions change. I distinctly remember writing CoASH, in fact, but that was many years ago. There may well be a rationale for the change/variation. Anyway readers may encounter different abbreviations for the same thing.

Comment: Okay, thanks for these hints. This may will diminish understanding issues.